# Empty table displays error

Tags: php

In the beginning , Users table is empty , and hence call is made to the function student is giving "UNDEFINED USER" instead of empty json code.
This is the function:

```
public function student() 
        {
             $result= mysql_query(" select * from users where cat_id=1 ");

              while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                    {
                     $user[]=array_filter($row);
                    }
                    return $user;    
        }
```

This is the function call made.

```
$user['student']=$obj->student();
       echo json_encode( $user);
```

Kindly help me remove this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all dont use `mysql_*` api, its deprecated, use [**PDO**](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) instead

Here is the updated code for you, giving a **default** value to return `$user` will solve your issue

```
public function student() 
    {
         $result= mysql_query("select * from users where cat_id=1 ");
         //make default value as an empty array 
         $user = array();

         if($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                {
                 $user[]=array_filter($row);
            }
         }

         return $user;    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define `$user` which will be returned when 0 records is found.

```
$result= mysql_query(" select * from users where cat_id=1 ");

$user = array();

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $user[]=array_filter($row);
    }
}

return $user;
```

Then I've added `num_rows` condition, maybe you can remove that from this code. I'm not sure, I didn't test that.

Answer (score 0):

[mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) returns false if there are no rows, so the value of `$user` is never set, resulting in the error `$user is undefined`.

You could set `$user` to `[]` by default, or put some more robust error checking into place.

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
if (count($user) > 0) {
    return $user;
}
return false;
```

And handle the user object accordingly.